# jquery not working for id as array eg: $("#pageid[0]").val("1234");

Tags: jquery, arrays

i have a set of text boxes. I gave the id as an array as `pageid[]`

so id of  first text box is `pageid[0]`

Am trying to do some action on that based on id

for eg:

```
$("#pageid[0]").val("1234");
```

I'm not getting any error. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Why won't you give it the id `pageid0` ?!

Comment: i have many fields in the form and many validation is needed. if i gave it as array , i get the count(array) then validate ..

Comment: @gdoron..one doubt... if i gave name as you said assume there are 7 input pageid0 to pageid7 . i want to chek if any of the input is not empty. how will i loop and test.. how i know there is 7 fields? the fields are dynamic can be higher or lesser

Comment: `$('input[id^="pageid"]')` Do you want me to give an answer  to that question instead of comments?

Comment: yea sure you can provide answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#pageid\\[0\\]").val("1234");
```

Oh and by the way you have invalid HTML because according to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So `[` and `]` should not be used in your ids and names.

Comment: It works . Thanks.. So is that the only proper way to use arrays?

Comment: Source? please give a link. I used the id `dsa`$fd so it's not true. you just need to escape it wil `\\` as you did

Comment: @zod. No the proper way is set the id to be `pageid0` not `pageid[0]`

Comment: @gdoron, of course here's the official source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2 . According to it `$` is not valid neither.

Comment: You can have array like syntax for your input names, but it is the server side language that actually parses it, the browser will just send the name as-is.  For IDs you should stick to valid identifier names for compatibility.

Comment: _"If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\."_ docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: +1 what I was typing: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines C.8  I am still perplexed as to the number of people who try to use non-unique ID with odd characters since this spec is 1999 (13 years old)

Comment: as per above comments and answer if i dont use array .. if i gave name as you said assume there are 7 input pageid0 to pageid7 . i want to chek if any of the input is not empty. how will i loop and test.. how i know there is 7 fields? the fields are dynamic can be higher or lesser

Answer (score 1):

Your selector would match this unhealthy div:

```
<div id="pageid" 0="whatever">
```

The meaning of your selector:

- id selector: `#pageid`
- has attribute selector: `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Change from `pageid[0]` to `pageid0` and select all the elements that starts with `pageid`:

```
var allFilled = $('input[id^="pageid"]').filter(function(){
                    return !this.value 
                }).length === 0

if (!allFilled)
    alert('Please fill all the ...')
```

[starts with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: this help me for sure . but in future..this is new for me. if i do this change i have to do some server side change also. am not accepting yours as answer bcoz the question was different. but +1 :-)